# google colaboratoryでgpu使ったら、ResourceExhaustedErrorと表示

Tags: keras, gpu, google-colaboratory

google colabでKarasを使ったNotebookを実行。

No-GPUだと、エラー表示が無かった。

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor of shape [3,3,256,512] and type float
     [[Node: training_1/SGD/zeros_14 = Const[dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=Tensor<type: float shape: [3,3,256,512] values: [[[0 0 0]]]...>, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1e944e6043cb> in <module>()
----> 1 hist_obj = deconvNet.Train()
```

以下、そんな感じのリソース足らないメッセージがてんこ盛り。。

よろしくおねがいします。

ソースコード　Notebook

```
!pip install pydot
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties     module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass
!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret= 
{creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} - secret={creds.client_secret}
```

:
:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda, Flatten, Reshape, 
Concatenate,Activation
from keras.layers import concatenate
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, ZeroPadding2D,MaxPooling2D, 
Cropping2D, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras import metrics
from keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers
from keras import losses
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import time
import numpy as np
import skimage.io as io
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import pydot
from pyemd import emd, emd_samples
```

Answer (score 1):

英語版に関連した質問と回答があります。

[Google Colaboratory: misleading information about its GPU (only 5% RAM available to some users)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48750199)

要約すると、GPUのRAMが500MBしかもらえない場合が多いということです。そのため、リソース不足のメッセージが出たものと思われます。

対応としては、GPUのRAMが500MBでも動作するようにブログラムを修正するぐらいしかなさそうです。

英語版の質問にあった次のコードを使って最初にGPUのメモリーを確認しておくと便利だと思います。この回答を書く前に試してみたらGPUのRAM11GBをすべて使える状態でした。

```
# memory footprint support libraries/code
!ln -sf /opt/bin/nvidia-smi /usr/bin/nvidia-smi
!pip install gputil
!pip install psutil
!pip install humanize
import psutil
import humanize
import os
import GPUtil as GPU
GPUs = GPU.getGPUs()
# XXX: only one GPU on Colab and isn’t guaranteed
gpu = GPUs[0]
def printm():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    print("Gen RAM Free: " + humanize.naturalsize( psutil.virtual_memory().available ), " | Proc size: " + humanize.naturalsize( process.memory_info().rss))
    print("GPU RAM Free: {0:.0f}MB | Used: {1:.0f}MB | Util {2:3.0f}% | Total {3:.0f}MB".format(gpu.memoryFree, gpu.memoryUsed, gpu.memoryUtil*100, gpu.memoryTotal))
printm()

Gen RAM Free: 12.6 GB  | Proc size: 140.1 MB
GPU RAM Free: 11439MB | Used: 0MB | Util   0% | Total 11439MB
```